# i got error undefind variable in blade page

Tags: laravel

Following is a dynamic button of the Datatable.

```
<button type="button" id="stud_info_download" class="btn btn-info btn-circle" onclick='download_stud_info(this.id)'><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#invoice" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Following is the ajax call.

```
 $(document).ready(function download_invoice() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "download_stud_info" + id,
        method: "POST",
    });
});
```

Here is the route for the same.

```
Route::post('download_stud_info/{id}','StudentRegistrationController@download_info');
```

Below is the blade file where I want to set the data from the database.

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="7" style=""><img src="assets_admin/images/workfreaks_logos.jpg" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;"> </td>
   <td width="425" class="text-center">
      <h4>Invoice #: WCINV316</h4>
      <h4 class="font-bold" style="font-size: 30px"><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>25,200.00,</h4>
      <p class="mt-4"><b>D.O.B: {{$download->DOB}}</b></p>
</tr>
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please share the code in the controller i.e. the method download_info , which returns the blade page, because it looks the you are not returning the data properly to the blade template.

Comment: Can you post the error code

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
{{$download->DOB}}
```

when You remove this Variable from you blade Your Error will be resolved

But the main problem is in your Controller

Comment: function download_info(Request $request)
{
    $download = invoice::find($request->id);
    return view('admin.client.add_invoice',compact('download'));
}
THIS IS MY CONTROLLER CAN YOU TELL ME WHAT IS ISSUE IN CONTROLLER
I WANT THIS DUE DATE on blade page